# Why doesn't delayed expansion work as parameter in a for command

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I want to execute some for loops for every path provided in a variable. The `echo !temp!` works just fine, however the for commands below it won't work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set paths=(C:\test C:\test2)

for %%p in %paths% do (
    set temp=%%p
    echo !temp!
    for /r !temp! %%f in (*.h) do (echo %%f)
    for /r !temp! %%g in (*.h *.cpp) do (echo %%g)
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334209/nested-batch-for-loops

Comment: I think the problem is that the `for` command is handled *before* delayed expansion occurs, according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133) (see end of phase 2); you can overcome the problem in two ways: 1. change to the `!temp!` directory before the inner `for /R` loops and do not place `!temp!` after `/R`; 2. move the `for /R` loops to a subroutine, pass `!temp!` as an argument and use the `%1` expansion (see `call /?`)...

Comment: @CristiFati this question is indeed the same as your post. I found the solution there. What should I do with this question? Remove?

Comment: Probably someone with enough privileges should mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all [`for` commands](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) syntax patterns:

```
  FOR %%parameter IN (set) DO command 
  FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command 
  FOR /D %%parameter IN (folder_set) DO command 
  FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command 
  FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command 
  FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ("Text string to process") DO command
  FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ('command to process') DO command
```

all text preceding `%%parameter` should be known in the first parsing phase. Read [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/3439404).

However, next script should work as expected

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "paths=(C:\test C:\test2)"

for %%p in %paths% do (
    set "temp=%%~p"
    echo !temp!
    call :doit
)

rem skip procedure
goto :domore

:doit
    for /r "%temp%" %%f in (*.h) do (echo %%f)
    for /r "%temp%" %%g in (*.h *.cpp) do (echo %%g)
goto :eof

:domore
```